# How to run Redshift copy command from EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have my log files on EC2 instance and want to load it to Redshift. Two questions:

1. Do I have to copy this log file to S3 before proceeding or can I directly copy from my EBS Volume.
2. I can see I can use copy command from  SQL Workbench or Data Pipeline. But can I use it from my EC2 instance itself ? Which AWS CLI I need to install?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/ does
not list copy command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the documentation available online was confusing me. Finally the solution was that I wrote a simple Java file with DriverManager.getConnection() and calling copy command via stmt.executeUpdate() and it worked seamlessly. Only executeUpdate() did not return me number of records Inserted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really. Redshift allows you to `copy` from a remote host, which, in your case, would be your EC2 instance. Documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-ssh.html).
2. The link you've referred to provides cluster management commands. To run SQL queries on your cluster, you can use the psql tool. Documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can copy the data directly from EC2, but my recommendation is to save it first on S3 , also for a backup

Comment: I already have backup of original log file on  S3..This is a transformed log file. How can I copy directly from EC2 instance ?

Comment: how can I copy directly from EC2 ?